# Verify (without Banach Contraction Priciple), that the function g(x) = 1 + x - (1/8)x^3 has a unique fixed point

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I know how to show that there exist a solution by the intermediate value theorem but I'm not sure how to show that the root is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  A fixed point is one where $g(x)=x$, so you might look for roots of $h(x)=g(x)-x$

Comment: If you put, for example x= 5 and x=-5 into h(x) you get a positive answer and a negative answer which then shows there exists a solution but how then do you use h(x) to show uniqueness?

Comment: @Megan: can you solve $h(x)=0$ exactly?

Comment: You can just solve $h(x)=0$ and find there is only one root.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. I was just over complicating it.